# Font for tagline under logo

Tags: fonts, logo, font-recommendation

Advise a font that could be used to write a fairly wide inscription consisting of 3-4 words under a logo (listing of some components, for example, if it is a workshop logo). The final composition is in the shape of a rectangle with an aspect ratio of about 1:4. The font size for the inscription is much smaller than that used in the main logo.

Comment: This would depend entirely upon the logo itself and it's marketing goals.

Comment: If you can edit your question to include more details about your objectives, we'll be more likely to make good recommendations. As it stands, it's a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

We love recommending fonts on here, but a bit of context would be nice. Do you want us to recommend you a font that's special and not everywhere, or are you on a tight budget? Should the font itself be narrow or wide? What mood do you want it to convey? Were you thinking the smaller text would be in all-caps, or lower-case? Do you have fonts you were considering, and if you rejected then why? I could imagine  myself recommending (starting with some from top designers) [Obviously](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GI4qzUWfg4), which has tons of weights and widths (that's the YouTube commercial, here's the [main site](https://ohnotype.co/fonts/families/obviously-normal)), or as a serif [Financier](https://klim.co.nz/retail-fonts/financier-text/), say, or [Caslon Doric Condensed](https://commercialclassics.com/catalog/caslon_doric/caslon_doric_condensed_text/medium).